# SQL Query to Remove All Product Information Magento

Tags: mysql, magento

So I am looking for the ability to remove all products and their attributes from magento.  Selecting all and then removing them from within the admin panel takes too long.  Right now I am doing massive bulk imports and tweaking data until it looks right.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity;
```

This table is linked to by dozens of other tables, but the foreign key "CASCADE" feature built in to MySQL InnoDB should automatically delete the corresponding entries in those tables as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSH (or Telnet) access to a server console, I'd recommend to dump the "clean" (no products/only base attributes) database version to a `.sql` file:

```
$ mysqldump -h dbhost -u dbuser -p dbname > dump.sql
```

Then you can test and tweak whatever you want, without any worries. At any point you want to restore your "clean" version, you can do this by simply executing:

```
$ mysql -h dbhost -u dbuser -p dbname < dump.sql
```